# Step response of feedback system

Tags: control-system, matlab, stability, frequency-response

We have a feedback system F(s) as in this figure:

[image]

[image: G(s)]

and this is the step response of G(s):

[image]

and H=10.

F(s):

[image]

We got the root locus of the system F(s) as this:

[image]

then we determined the gain at marginal stability:

[image]

which is equal to 2.5.

Then, we made H = 2.57 (slightly larger than 2.5) and we obtained the step response of the new system Fh(s). Here is it with the step response of the original system F(s):

[image]

Then, we made H = 2.43 (slightly lower than 2.5) and we obtained the step response of the new system Fl(s). Here is it with the step response of the original system F(s):

[image]

My questions:

- What can we know from the step response plot of G(s)?
- What can we know from the step response plot of F(s)?
- When we changed the gain to 2.57, how did the system F(s) change? What can we conclude by comparing the step responses of F(s) and Fh(s)?
- When we changed the gain to 2.43, how did the system F(s) change? What can we conclude by comparing the step responses of F(s) and Fl(s)?

Comment: What are your answers?

Comment: This question and MATLAB outputs are awfully homeworky looking

Comment: 1. G(s) unstable.
2. It's overdamped and F(s) is stable.
3. Fh(s) becomes underdamped.
4. Fl(s) becomes unstable.
I don't know if my answers are correct. Even if they are, I need some details and explanations.

Comment: Give me a link where I can read about step responses and stability because I've searched but found no good results.

Comment: Over 20 seconds to respond to a step change (graph 1)?

Comment: @Andy aka, the scale on the vertical axis goes up to \$\small 2.10^{13}\$, and \$\small 10^{27}\$ further on!!

Answer (score 1):

- G(s) is unstable because the step-response doesn't have a steady-state value. It goes to infinity.
- F(s) is stable since its step response has a steady-state value near 0.1. It's underdamped response.
- Fh(s) is stable since its step response has a steady-state value near 0.2. It's underdamped response with more oscillations than F(s).
- Fl(s) is unstable because it doesn't have a steady-state value. It has a very large oscillations that start after some time.